# Training CNN model by using activation function Selu

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training my own model using Tensorflow. However, I got some trouble when I change my activation function from Relu to Selu.

This is what happened. Learning curve drops accidentally and I have no idea about what's going on.

my learning curve

[image]

like this.

For what I have known, Selu can prevent overfitting, so I try to implement it in my model. Is there any tips, or any condition when I want to use Selu?

This is my code:

#### this is the place where I change my activation function

#### -----

```
def conv2d_maxpool(x_tensor, conv_num_outputs, conv_ksize, conv_strides, pool_ksize, pool_strides, layer_name):

conv_layer = tf.layers.conv2d(x_tensor, conv_num_outputs, kernel_size=conv_ksize, strides=conv_strides, activation=tf.nn.selu, name = layer_name)   
conv_layer = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_layer, pool_size=pool_ksize, strides=pool_strides)

return conv_layer
```

#### -----

### graph

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

#### placeholder ####
input_img = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, img_size, img_size, 3))
y_true = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, num_class))
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")
lr_in = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, name  = 'learning_rate')

conv_ksize = (3,3)
conv_strides = (1,1)
pool_ksize = (2,2)
pool_strides = (2,2)
n_filters_1 = 32
n_filters_2 = 64
n_filters_3 = 128
n_filters_4 = 256
onebyone_ksize = (1,1)

#CNN
conv_1 = conv2d_maxpool(input_img, n_filters_1, conv_ksize, conv_strides, pool_ksize, pool_strides, layer_name = "conv1")

# conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_1, conv_num_outputs, kernel_size=conv_ksize, strides=conv_strides, activation=tf.nn.relu)  

# conv_1_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv_1, name = "batch_norm1")
# conv_1_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(conv_1_norm, rate = keep_prob, training = True, name = "dropout1")

conv_2 = conv2d_maxpool(conv_1, n_filters_2, conv_ksize, conv_strides, pool_ksize, pool_strides, layer_name = "conv2")
# conv_2_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv_2)

conv_3 = conv2d_maxpool(conv_2, n_filters_3, conv_ksize, conv_strides, pool_ksize, pool_strides, layer_name = "conv3")
# conv_3_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv_3, name = "batch_norm3")
# conv_3_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(conv_3_norm, rate = keep_prob, training = True, name = "dropout3")

conv_4 = conv2d_maxpool(conv_3, n_filters_4, conv_ksize, conv_strides, pool_ksize, pool_strides, layer_name = "conv4")


flatten = tf.layers.flatten(conv_4)

fc1 = tf.layers.dense(flatten, 256, activation = tf.nn.relu)

out = tf.layers.dense(fc1, 6, activation=None, name= "logits") #logit

predict = tf.nn.softmax(out)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = out, labels = y_true))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(cost)

##accuracy
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out, 1), tf.argmax(y_true, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
```

## Training

```
#history/record
train_loss, train_acc = [], []
valid_loss, valid_acc = [], []
update_per_epoch = int(np.floor(X_train.shape[0] / batch_size))

## early stopping and learning rate congig
es_patience = 10
es_n = 0

lr_patience = 3
lr_n = 0

save_model_path = './save'

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)


# Initializing the variables
batch_gen = img_gen.flow(generator_input(X_train), y_train, batch_size = 32)
val_batch_gen = img_gen.flow(generator_input(X_valid), y_valid, batch_size = len(X_valid))

for i in range(epoch):

    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc  = 0

    for j in range(update_per_epoch):                    


        image, label = next(batch_gen)

        _, this_loss, this_acc = sess.run([optimizer, cost, accuracy], feed_dict={
            input_img : image,
            y_true : label,
            lr_in: lr,
            keep_prob : keep_probability
        })

        epoch_loss += this_loss
        epoch_acc += this_acc

    ## end of epoch

    epoch_loss /= update_per_epoch
    epoch_acc /= update_per_epoch

    train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
    train_acc.append(epoch_acc)

    print('Epoch {:>2}   Loss: {:>4.4f} Training Accuracy: {:.6f}'.format(i + 1, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))



    valid_image, valid_label = next(val_batch_gen)

    valid_this_loss, valid_this_acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict = {
        input_img: valid_image,
        y_true: valid_label,
        lr_in: lr,
        keep_prob: 1.
    })

    valid_loss.append(valid_this_loss)
    valid_acc.append(valid_this_acc)

    print('Epoch {:>2}   Loss: {:>4.4f} Validation Accuracy: {:.6f}'.format(i + 1,valid_this_loss, valid_this_acc))



    # early stop

    if valid_this_loss > np.min(valid_loss):
        es_n += 1
        lr_n += 1
    else:
        es_n = 0
        lr_n = 0
        saver.save(sess, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'bestsession.ckpt'))

    # early stop
    if es_n >= es_patience:
        print("-----------early stopping-------------")
        break

    # adaptive learning rate

    if lr_n >= lr_patience:
        lr *= lr_decay_rate
        lr_n = 0
        print("-----------adjust learning rate------------")







# Save Model
save_path = saver.save(sess, save_model_path)
print('-----model save ------')
```

-----------    18/09/07------------

I can always reproduce the same result.

And this is my code, I wrote it in Jupyter. But sorry I can't upload the training data:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uUE32KrNmWnhLbV8z-fyHSMu6zGCCG_e

Comment: Can you reproduce this consistently across multiple runs? If so, I would also head over to the TensorFlow GitHub and open an issue. To me the code seems fine (especially, since it trains well in the beginning... One question might be what values for learning rate and decay you are using. I suspect numerical instabilities at some point.

Comment: yes, I always get the same result at the end of training. The learning rate is 1.7e-3(0.0017) and the decay rate is 0.9.

Also, I put the whole code in my question.